# Editor for Linux Mint?

Tags: texstudio, editors

**Update:** Gummi installed with no problem and seems to work. Thanks...

I need to install some sort of TeX editor on Linux Mint (19.1 "Tessa"). The Software Manager kindly offers to install TeXStudio but that fails with a 404. The install script at https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/texstudio also fails, could not retrieve a few packages. For the heck of it I execute "texstudio" in a terminal window - it says it's not installed but can be installed with **sudo apt [something]"** - that also fails to retrieve a few packages.

If anyone has an idea how a Linux weenie can install TeXStudio or some other suitable TeX editor that would be fabulous.

Comment: Why not just use Overleaf? Do you need to be offline?

Comment: I believe a lot of editors are platform independent now, but I can be mistaken of course. Here is a very useful post about most recorded possibilities https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides. I started on texmaker, then atom-latex, and now I am working on VSCode+LaTeX-Workshop. Both last editors should be functionning on Linux OSs. See here for VSCode https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Comment: Here is the official TeXstudio website: https://www.texstudio.org and you can download the xUbuntu version there (Mint is not listed; I use Mint).

Comment: @Sigur Thanks. There are five or six different xUbunutu packages there - sorry to be a moron, but how do I tell which one I want?

Comment: You have to know your distribution. Maybe you have Mint 2020. I have Mint 18.

Comment: @Sigur I know it's Mint 19.1 - I don't know how that says which xUbuntu package I want, sorry.

Comment: So, try xUbuntu 19.04. It should work. Download the .deb file and after just double click on it.

Comment: @Sigur "Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libc6 (>= 2.29)"

Comment: You can try the 18 version or update the that library.

Comment: Linux Mint repositories have packages for several LaTeX editors as gummi, texworks, texstudio,  tekmaker, latexila, kile the document processor (not Ljust a LaTeX editor) lyx. There are also many packages for general text editors with more or less support for LaTeX editing,  including,  of course, emacs and  vim,  but also geany, atom, sublime-text, xed, and even non-GUI text editors as nano or mcedtit support LaTeX syntax highlight.

Comment: @Fran Thanks. See Update to question: I got Gummi installed.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Gummi is good but use /tmp to compile a temporal copy. This sometimes produce problems, for intance, using` \jobname`. Install also at least another text editor as texworks for this cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be 2 issues here.

First, a 404 error is (I think) related to the fact that you tried to download software but it wasn't there; this explains why you were told it wasn't installed. I went to the Linux Mint forums and found [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1648850#p1648850) which says:

Question: "/etc/apt/sources.list is the usual location of the repository list for debian systems. Mint is a debian based system, but the repository list is not here. Where is it in Tessa, 19.1?"

followed by

Answer: "On Mint the main repository list file has been /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list for years now.
The smartest way of querying the software sources list files, configured on your own system, is by executing the terminal command inxi -r." which is followed by a screenshot of what to expect.

The answer solved the problem. So I think it's a matter of `sudo apt-get` to the appropriate spot. Here is a link about dealing with [404 errors](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/fix-404-errors-with-ubuntu-ppas/) with Ubuntu (which Mint is built from).

Second, with respect to LaTeX editors, I like Gummi for small documents, Kile for long documents, and use the online editor [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) when working with `sagetex` and [SAGE](https://www.sagemath.org/) . You can go to your software center, search on `latex` and get what's available for Mint 19.1. For Mint 18 I have

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's what 404 means, sorry. Thanks - I may try Gummi and Kile.

Answer (score 3):

I'd offer an unpopular opinion.

## Emacs

1. [Install Emacs](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/emacs), preferably with GUI.
2. Create a proper [init file](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InitFile) for more usual for yourself keybinding, there are a lot of [starter packages](https://github.com/caisah/emacs.dz) out there. Be aware, that a proper customisation can take weeks.
3. [Add](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started) MELPA repository to it. In most "batteries included" init files it is already there.
4. [Install](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Installation.html) AucTeX.
5. Install additional packages for graphical preview, `latexmk`, reverse indexing, and so on, if you need them.
6. This has nothing to do with Emacs, but I feel that it is a good suggestion: start using `git` early.

Such a setup is portable across Linuces, Mac OS, all the exotic old UNIX OSes, and even Windows. Even if something breaks away, you will be able to fix it. So, basically, getting a working Emacs environment is an investment for life.

Comment: are there other editors?

Comment: Why is this "unpopular"?

Comment: @davidc it doesn't mention vim.

Comment: Yes! Steep [learning curve](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_fun.html), but you don’t need to try learning everything at once, and Emacs repays your efforts many times over.